Stacking/duplicating rows in a DataFrame using only a subset of columns
I have a problem I just can`t find a working solution for.
As a starting point, I have an array created from an XML file containing the following information:
| Location | Description | Status | ..... | Product| Name | Price | Product| Name | Price | ...
| 1        | "Foo"       | 1      |       |        | 124  | 4.2   |        | 122  | 8.8   |
| 2        | "Bar"       | 1      |       |        | 122  | 8.9   |        | NaN  | NaN   |

The first n columns contain generic information, which is the same for all "products" in the corresponding row. The last 24 columns contain 8 subsets of 3 columns with the same repeating set of names ["Product", "Name", "Price"].
For further handling of the data, I want to "stack" the data of the last 24 columns as subsets of three to get something like this:
| Location | Description | Status | ..... | Product| Name | Price |
| 1        | "Foo"       | 1      |       |        | 124  | 4.2   |
|          |             |        |       |        | 122  | 8.8   |
| 2        | "Bar"       | 1      |       |        | 122  | 8.9   |
|          |             |        |       |        | NaN  | NaN   |

or
| Location | Description | Status | ..... | Product| Name | Price |
| 1        | "Foo"       | 1      |       |        | 124  | 4.2   |
| 1        | "Foo"       | 1      |       |        | 122  | 8.8   |
| 2        | "Bar"       | 1      |       |        | 122  | 8.9   |
| 2        | "Bar"       | 1      |       |        | NaN  | NaN   |

I have tried to solve my transformation problem as follows:
Step 1: De-duplicate the identical column names (to later be able to use df.stack():
cols=pd.Series(result_list_xml_t[0])
for dup in cols[cols.duplicated()].unique(): 
    cols[cols[cols == dup].index.values.tolist()] = [dup + '.' + str(i) if i != 0 else dup for i in range(sum(cols == dup))]

Step 2: Create a MultiIndex to group
columns_xml = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([xml_groups,cols])

With this, I create a pandas df that looks like:
  | base                                    | prod1                       | prod 2
  | Location | Description | Status | ..... | Product.1| Name.1 | Price.1 | Product.2| Name.2 | Price.2 | ...
1 | 1        | "Foo"       | 1      |       |          | 124    | 4.2     |          | 122    | 8.8     |
2 | 2        | "Bar"       | 1      |       |          | 122    | 8.9     |          | NaN    | NaN     |

Now, I would like to only stack the prod-groups while maintaining the base-group. Can this be done by using the stack-function or is there another, more efficient approach?
I tried to work with df.stack because of this thread:
Stack Overflow - Unnnest multi index data frame
but df.stack(future_stack=True,level=0) does not seem to get me closer to my desired format.
  |            | base  | prod1 | prod2 | prod3| ...
0 | Location   | 1     |
0 | Description| "Foo" |
0 | Status     | 1     |
...
0 | Product.1  |       |       |      |      |
0 | Name.1     |       | 124   |      |      |
0 | Price.1    |       | 4.2   |      |      |
...

I also tried to go with a combination of .melt() and .set_index() proposed by the following thread Unstack or Pivot in Pandas, but that also did not get me closer.

Create MultiIndex by first n columns first by DataFrame.set_index, create counter in duplicated columns by GroupBy.cumcount, so possible use DataFrame.stack:
print (df)
   Location Description  Status Product  Name  Price Product   Name  Price
0         1         Foo       1       a   124    4.2       v  122.0    8.8
1         2         Bar       1       b   122    8.9       b    NaN    NaN

n = 3
out = df.set_index(df.columns[:n].tolist())
out.columns = [out.columns, out.columns.to_series().groupby(level=0).cumcount()]

out = out.stack(dropna=False).droplevel(-1).reset_index()
print (out)
   Location Description  Status Product   Name  Price
0         1         Foo       1       a  124.0    4.2
1         1         Foo       1       v  122.0    8.8
2         2         Bar       1       b  122.0    8.9
3         2         Bar       1       b    NaN    NaN


Hello jezrael, thank you for your solution, which sent me down the right path. Unfortunatelly, the number of columns before the subset of the 3-column-groups ist not consistent and can range from 1 to 18 counted columns. However, by simply changing the value for n to 1, i got my desired output (The first code-block in the question.) . Thank you again.

@mazwing - You are welcome.

Why don't you just cut the data frame? In my example, you have 3 products, you can replace it with
df = pd.DataFrame({'Location': [1,2], 'Description': ["Foo", "Bar"], 'Status': [1,1],
                 'Product': ["",""], 'Name': [124, 124], "Price": [4.2, 6.5], 
                 'Product1': ["",""], 'Name1': [125, 124], "Price1": [4.2, 6.2],
                 'Product2': ["",""], 'Name2': [125, np.nan], "Price2": [4.2, 15]}
                 )
df = df.rename(columns={'Product1': 'Product', 'Product2': 'Product',
          'Price1': 'Price', 'Price2': 'Price',
           'Name1': 'Name', 'Name2': 'Name'
          })

    





Location
Description
Status
Product
Name
Price
Product
Name
Price
Product
Name
Price




0
1
Foo
1

124
4.2

125
4.2

125.0
4.2


1
2
Bar
1

124
6.5

124
6.2

NaN
15.0



sub_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns[:3+3], index = range(df.shape[0]*3)) #generaly :n+3 and df.shape[0]*8

for i in range(3): #8
    sliced_df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :3], df.iloc[:, 3+i*3: 3+(i+1)*3]], axis = 1) #[:,:n] and [:n+i*8, n+(i+1)*8] in general
    sub_df.iloc[i*df.shape[0]:(i+1)*df.shape[0],:] = sliced_df

sub_df





Location
Description
Status
Product
Name
Price




0
1
Foo
1

124
4.2


1
2
Bar
1

124
6.5


2
1
Foo
1

125
4.2


3
2
Bar
1

124
6.2


4
1
Foo
1

125.0
4.2


5
2
Bar
1

NaN
15.0




Hello, thank you for your answer. I tried it, but ran into a problem. In my df, there are 20 unique columns before the 8 sets of 3-column-groups begin. I set n=19 to account for zero-indexing and tried your generalized formula. From what i can see in the output, in this approach the code duplicates every row eight times, however, the values for the name and price column are "lost". Might you be able to give me a hint, where I'm understanding the indexing wrong?   Thank you.

If you have 20 columns at the beginning, you should take n=20, not 19.  in ranges, the first element is included in the interval, so starting from column n=20, you will take the 21st column and stop before column with index 23, which is 24th.
Alternatively, if your product columns are always last in the sheet, you can select them by backward indexing.
